# How to populate table in chrome extension using script

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to populate table using array in chrome extension

I am currently making a chrome extension with a table which I would like to populate. The following code works on a standalone index.html file:

```
 <table id="table" border="1">


    </table>

    <script>

        var array = [["First"],
                     ["Second"],
                     ["Third"]]

        table = document.getElementById("table");

       for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       {
           // create a new row
           var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
           for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
           {
               // create a new cell
               var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

               // add value to the cell
               cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
           }
       }
    </script>
```

However, when I paste this script into my chrome extension which contains a table, nothing happens. I am new to javascript so i am wondering if this is possible and how i can make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with content scripts. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions have a rule in which no inline scripts can be in the HTML.
look in your CTRL-SHIFT-J(JS console).

The solution(without content scripts) is to use external source files, eg. `<script src="myfile.js"></script>`

This includes onloads and onclicks, FYI.